# How to pass down parameter using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<td><%= link_to "See Chart", "#AddChartModal" %> </td>

<%= render partial: 'searches/chart', locals: {senid: sensor.id} %>
```

Like the code above, I'll like to pass down @sensors to another controller.

```
<td><%= link_to "Results", "folder_name/file_name" %> </td>
```

Is there a way to pass down @sensors using link_to to another controller?

Comment: `<%= link_to "Results", "path of your action (sensors: @sensors)" %>` for an example `<%= link_to "Results", articles_path(sensors: @sensors) %> `

Comment: @Vishal - I don't think `articles_path(sensors: @sensors)` is going to give you what you think it's going to give you.

Comment: @jvillian I just gave an example of how to pass parameters with link to, what particular she wants to send, like ids. it's up to her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have `@sensors` that is an enumerable that responds to `ids`. And also assuming in your `routes.rb`, you have something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :results
end
```

...then you could do something like:

```
<td><%= link_to "Results", results_path(sensor_ids: @sensor.ids) %> </td>
```

Which will give you something like:

```
<a href="/results?sensor_ids%5B%5D=3&sensor_ids%5B%5D=4">Results</a>
```

When you click on the link, you'll have something like:

```
Started GET "/results?sensor_ids%5B%5D=3&sensor_ids%5B%5D=4" for ::1 at 2019-08-20 21:36:50 -0700
Processing by ResultsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"sensor_ids"=>["3", "4"]}
```

In your `ResultsController`, then, you can do something like:

```
#app/controllers/results_controller.rb
class ResultsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @sensors = Sensor.where(id: params[:sensor_ids])
    ...
  end

end
```

...and now you'll have `@sensors` in your `ResultsController`.

Comment: It is giving me an error undefined method `ids' because @sensors is an array. How can I pass down each ids in the array?

Comment: An array of what? If it is an array of objects that respond to `.id`, then you could probably do `@sensors.map(&:id)` or, possibly, `@sensors.pluck(:id)`.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= link_to "Results", results_path(senid: sensor.id) %>` would give you a link to something like `/results?senid=123`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "See Chart", "chart_path(sensor_id: @sensor.id)" %>
```

This is how you can pass sensor id to chart controller.